# jQuery Mobile and Normal jQuery

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

I am playing around with jQuery Mobile as I am hoping to be able to develop digital publications strictly for the iPad.

I have no problem understanding the basics of this as I am quite 'in the know' with jQuery as it stands. My problem is - can you still use normal jQuery functions and events when in the mobile wrapper?

I am running this code to initiate a tap event on a fixed position div to show another absolutely positioned div which is off page (a contents selector)

```
($)(function(){

    $('.indexPage').live('swipeleft swiperight', function(event){

        if(event.type == 'swipeleft') {
            $.mobile.changePage( "index2.html", {type: 'get'});
        }

        if(event.type == 'swiperight') {
            $.mobile.changePage( "index.html", {type: 'get',reverse: true}  );
        }

    });

    $('#sticky').live('tap', function(event){

        console.log('#sticky tapped');

        $('#contents').show();
    });

});
```

Can anyone shed any light on the matter?

Comment: Might I add - this works on a normal browser FF5 on Mac - but obviously it's a click event ;)

Comment: Yes for jQuery functions but it's touch for events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, I'd say yes you can. For example all my bindings of the change events still works perfectly.

However I'd say that it's better to avoid mouse events and to use the virtual mouse events provided by jQuery mobile instead. And all the plugin you might want to use probably won't work (for example, some part of jQuery-UI are not working).

Comment: Thanks guys, 

It seems you can't attach events to DIV's with ID's, they have to be classes - so in this case .contents as opposed to #contents. I would answer my own question but have to wait 7 hours :( gief moar rep plx.

Comment: That's some weird stuff. It's a bug imho. jQuerymobile is supposed to be: "Built on jQuery core for familiar and consistent jQuery syntax and minimal learning curve".

Comment: I just tested in my code, and it works just fine.
`$("#imgDiv").bind("vclick",function(){console.log("hello");});`
diplays a nice hello in my console. It must be related to something else.